# Has Waldo become some kind of Big Brother?

Tags: black-mirror

In the Black Mirror (S02E03) episode called *The Waldo Moment*, we see a cartoon character having more importance than it should.

At the end,

> It is on screens, on shows from all over the world.

So we can imagine it has become some Big Brother, not in the "watching you" way, but in the way of a concept to keep people, with a common image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the intent is that Waldo has been co-opted by Jack Napier and the man from "the agency". They've taken Jamie's counter-cultural icon and are now using it to help the government control the people.

Here's some commentary from the people involved on the episode.

So yes, in a manner of speaking, he's the public face of Big Brother, a way to communicate with and control the common people.

Comment: The man from 'The Agency' said that Waldo had "the potential to become a Global Authority Figure". It seems that's exactly what they turned him into, despite the fact that he technically lost the election.

Comment: {nods} Which, now that I think of it, does fit with what the querent was asking.

Comment: @Bebs, your thoughts?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots, sorry for the late answer. It's clear now. Your video was useful, I did miss som points first time.

Comment: No worries at all. :)